# creation of empty sheets when export worksheets vba

Tags: vba, excel

code :

```
Dim sItem As String
Dim backslash As String

Private Sub browse_Button_Click()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim strPath As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
showFilePath.Text = sItem
backslash = Right(sItem, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub cancel_button_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub export_button_Click()
If showFilePath = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select a folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
If (backslash = Chr(92)) Then
    FolderName = sItem & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
Else
    FolderName = sItem & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
End If
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
        If xlsx = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsm = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xls = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsb = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            Unload Me
        ElseIf csv = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
            Unload Me
        ElseIf txt = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4158
            Unload Me
        ElseIf txt_unicode = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = 42
            Unload Me
        ElseIf html = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".html": FileFormatNum = 44
            Unload Me
        ElseIf mhtml = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".mhtml": FileFormatNum = 45
            Unload Me
        ElseIf prn = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".prn": FileFormatNum = 36
            Unload Me
        ElseIf dbf3 = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".dbf": FileFormatNum = 8
            Unload Me
        ElseIf dbf4 = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".dbf": FileFormatNum = 11
            Unload Me
        End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Userform : 
[image]

This code works when it is created as a separated `.xlsm` file. But when I made this a ribbon control as seen below, it doesnt work. Infact, it creates 3 empty sheets named as `Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3`. My sheets are named as `Budget, Profit`. Just 2 sheets , whereas the code creates 3 sheets, with different names and no records in it.

Please help required.

Ribbon control : 
[image]

Comment: Where does your code set the number of sheets and their names?

Comment: @SolarMike it doesn't. It directly exports all the worksheets, hence no need to set the number of sheets. And the names are the same which is in the workbook.

Comment: A good example of the difference between workbook names then... what excel assumes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ThisWorkbook` represents the workbook this code is running in.
- `ActiveWorkbook` repersents the workbook which is active (has focus) at the moment.

So you should probably change

```
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
```

into

```
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

if you use it as an addin. Otherwise it tries to access the sheets in the addin instead of your workbook.

Comment: That was amazing. Didn't know this would be the error. Thanx a lot.